# MySQL queries take longer as my python program fetches more data

Tags: python, mysql, sql

My SQL database has about 200k tables, and I'm making a simple program to fetch some of the data from every single table. The query looks something like:

```
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM `%s`" % (tablename))
```

As I loop through a list of table names and execute this query, it takes longer and longer each time. In the beginning it takes less than 1ms to run the query, but by the end its taking up to 70ms per query.

What could possibly be causing this slowdown? If I make the program sleep for 10 seconds halfway through, the query is still just as slow as before the sleep. The only thing that gets it fast again is restarting the program.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Your database has two hundred *thousand* tables? As you go from first to last table, do the tables contain more data? What happens if you start with the "last" table and walk to the "first"? Wild, probably worthless guess: it takes longer to access table #200,000 than it does to access table #1.

Comment: I would have my doubts that MySQL was optimized for 200,000 tables.

Comment: It smells like something is wrong with your design if you do, in fact, have 200,000 tables.

Comment: I tried reversing it and the slowdown still happens, and its still fast in the beginning. Something is definitely wrong with the design, but I don't think that's what's causing the slowdown.

Comment: If the first table you access, regardless of where it is in the database, happens quickly, and things slow down from there, it's possible that you're not disposing resources after you close each cursor. I'm not a python programmer, so a useful answer is beyond my abilities.

Comment: Yeah I thought about that, but it happens even if I never save any of the data at all. I'll look into a cur.close function though.

Comment: Per @BobKaufman's comment, if you can rule out python code (holding resources, filling memory etc) as the cause, it would seem that accessing that many tables in mysql is the cause. Perhaps the database is trying to cache data or has bugs which use up resources. For a practical short-term solution you could try closing and re-opening the connection every ~1000 tables. But I would also agree with other comments that this is too many tables and you should consolidate them.

Comment: Do you use same cursor and connection all the time? Opening connection in mysql is cheap, try creating new connection and cursor for each query. Moreover, may be your database is responding late due to high load because of your application.

Comment: Thanks, I'm working on consolidating the tables. I tried reconnecting every 1000 queries and that actually solved the problem. @Turophile submit it as an answer and I'll mark it correct. Thank you everyone for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is solved by reconnected to the database every 1000 requests.

Answer (score 0):

[posted as an answer as requested]

See the comments for some useful suggestions.

For a practical short-term solution you could try closing and re-opening the connection every ~1000 tables.

But the root cause is that you have too many tables, and you should address that problem if possible.